# Can I view iMessage history from an iPhone set up as a new device?

Tags: iphone, icloud, messages, ios

I set up a new iPhone as a new device (not from a backup) but using my same Apple ID for iCloud and so on. Can I view my old iMessages on this phone?

If I restore from backup, the messages appear. I set up the phone as a new device because I was getting some strange syncing behaviors.

I would really like to have my old conversations available. Any way to do this? Are they in iCloud somewhere? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can only restore your data (messages are part of your data) by restoring from backup. That should work fine, assuming that the backup iOS version and the new phone iOS version are the same. If your data backup is from an earlier iOS revision than your new phone, all bets are off.

Restoring your data from backup shouldn't introduce sync problems as the operating system of the phone is not part of the backup scheme.

Comment: That's good to know. I tried setting up as a new device because I was getting "Waiting to copy..." errors in iTunes. Very frustrating, and I thought it had something to do with restoring from backup.

Comment: Waiting to copy messages are not necessarily errors. Backups can be quite large. I just restored my iPhone 5 from backup the other day and the backup size was just short of 11GB. There are many thousands of files in such a large backup set, so a restore can take considerable time. If in doubt, ensure the PC from which you're restoring has been freshly rebooted. That can help avoid OS-related problems that might get in the way.